# Laravel - HTML to PDF conversion not working when moved from localhost to live server

Tags: pdf, laravel, laravel-4, dompdf

I am using HTML to PDF conversion [package provide by thujon on Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/thujohn/pdf) which works pretty well on my local mamp server, however, when moved to the live server (I am using shared hosting), I get plain text output with no spaces and no PDF is generated. I have just moved my code and have changed nothing. I believe the package is not loaded but I don't know how to get it working. Any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit 1: My PHP version is 5.5. Just copy pasting few lines from output for the idea:

```
%PDF-1.3 1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Outlines 2 
........................... 
..........................
0000002796 00000 n trailer << /Size 9 /Root 1 0 R /Info 5 0 R >> startxref 2905 %%EOF
```

Edit 2: Code for generating PDF (just a sample; this works fine on my local mamp server but generates above give output on the live server)

```
<?php 
$html = '';
$html .= '<html><head>';
$html .=  '</head><body>';
$html .= 'Test';
$html .= '</body></html>';
return PDF::load($html, 'a4', 'portrait')->show();
?>
```

Comment: Can anyone please help here?

Comment: have you checked that the php version on the server meets the requirements? (php >= 5.3.0 )

Comment: Yes, It is php 5.5..I will also update the question..

Comment: I suspect the headers aren't being sent correctly.
can you post the php code you're using to generate the pdf? everything that's relevant to generating the pdf itself.

Comment: Definitely, I will add a sample code to my question. However, the point is that..It is working fine on my local mamp server and not working when move to my live server (I am using the same browser). Its kind of very weird.

Comment: Someone else appears to have a similar issue to you https://github.com/thujohn/pdf-l4/issues/39.
try `return PDF::load($html, 'a4', 'portrait')->download('my_pdf');` and see if that works...at least then we have a better idea of what's going wrong.

Comment: So, well you are right. That does work on a chrome but on safari it downloads 'my_pdf.pdf.html'. Also, this is not a good solution since I am using this for an inventory bill printing and won't be good if I ask them to download and then print. Could you recommend something else?

Comment: BTW, I have also tried sending header as 'header('Content-type: application/pdf');' but the end result is same. No success.

Comment: according to the issue posted on github the headers aren't being sent properly. Do you have a public link so I can check what headers are being sent?

Comment: Give me few minutes, I will setup a public link.

Comment: So, here is the public link for the code I just posted: http://inventory.vamas.in/pdftest

Comment: Well it's definitely an issue with the headers being sent incorrectly.
What's strange is if the headers had already been sent, it looks like Thujohn's wrapper of dompdf should alert you of this...perhaps it's the server configuration itself that's causing the problem, though I find that quite unusual.

Comment: If you're still early on in development perhaps give this wrapper a go instead: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

It's the one I use and I've had no issues streaming pdfs with it.

Comment: Yea, I just downloaded it few minutes back. Will give it a try. I find it more weird because the same thing is working on local machine. Anyways, Thanks a ton  .>!

Comment: no problem, sorry I couldn't be more help...hopefully the new package works on your hosting. If not then you may need to raise a support ticket with them and find out what's up with their server setup.

Comment: It was actually a great help. Since, I would have sticked to this otherwise. Now, I know that it won't work so I can go with other approach. So, thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong in `a4` actual is `A4`. Take a try the following code in your `route.php` and call it from your browser like `yourdomain.com/pdfshowsimple`.

```
Route::get('/pdfshowsimple', function()
{
    $html = '<html><body>'
            . '<p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite '
            . 'templating system.</p>'
            . '</body></html>';
    return PDF::load($html, 'A4', 'portrait')->show();
});
```

You can see more detail usage about it at [here](https://github.com/thujohn/pdf-l4/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Really appreciate it. This is not the problem though. Just for reference I have my own page size defined in dompdf and the block letter won't make a difference. If you follow the comments you will just understand what I mean. Again, really appreciate your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at your local php info and your live server php info what is the different? I thought you need to configure your live server php.

Comment: Thank you but it's all done..please go through the comments..we already discussed on this issue and reached a conclusion.